# Is there any possibility of passing in specflow "Examples" as strings from elsewhere

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, specflow

Need some expertise with regards to passing Specflow Examples as strings from Database 
I know that we can setup examples in a Excel file and use them in a feature file ...but was wondering is it possible to pass Examples values from database tables ....any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: I have one question: _why_

Comment: Actually its not my idea as my product team want to use examples section to drive different variables of data from the database(tables and store procs)to validate different inputs ...

Comment: Not a good idea at all, specflow is meant to be readable above all else.